# Sticky Navigation Issue - "position: fixed" Possibly Not Taking Effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an eCommerce website which is hosted on a platform (Zoey Commerce). On this website, I have some very simple jQuery which will apply CSS to an element (the header navigation) in order to fix it at the top of the page, therefore creating a sticky navigation when scrolling.

The issue is that the header navigation element is fixing to the top of the page but it isn't travelling with the browser scroll, which isn't performing as `position: fixed` normally would do.

Please see the website here to see what is happening:

http://ts367609-container.zoeysite.com/

Please see my code below:

```
<script>
var num = 10; //number of pixels before modifying styles

jQuery(window).bind('scroll', function () {
    if (jQuery(window).scrollTop() > num) {
        jQuery('#global-wrapper-cp-142f9c37e921e052ae02cddde9be836b').addClass('fixed');
    } else {
        jQuery('#global-wrapper-cp-142f9c37e921e052ae02cddde9be836b').removeClass('fixed');
    }
});
</script>
```

CSS:

```
#pix-fe .fixed {
    position: fixed !important;
    z-index: 9999 !important;
    margin-top: 0 !important;
}
```

The code couldn't be much more simple, so it's leading me to think that the eCommerce platform is causing `position: fixed` to misbehave. Can anybody spot anything further that I've missed? Thank you very much for looking at this and I appreciate any answers in advance.

Comment: It has a lot to do with your margin-left: -1100% on #pix-. I suppose you can figure it out from there :).

Comment: Thank you. I'll look into this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `toggleClass` instead of `if..else` like this

```
$window.scroll(function() {
  $('#global-wrapper-cp-142f9c37e921e052ae02cddde9be836b').toggleClass('fixed', $(window).scrollTop() > num);
});
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thank you. I'll look into this and let you know.